# Необходима ли запятая после "Однако"?

Tags: запятая

Однако, чтобы добиться своего, нужно...

Answer (score 4):

В этом предложении **стык** сочинительного и подчинительного **союзов**.

Запятая на стыке союзов ставится, если после первого союза следует одиночный союз в придаточной части: ... А женщина всё говорила и говорила о своих несчастьях, и, хотя слова ее были привычными, у Сабурова от них вдруг защемило сердце (Сим.). Собака приостановилась, и, пока она стояла, человек видел, как солнечный луч обласкал всю полянку (Пришв.).

***В начале предложения не разделяются запятой сочинительный и подчинительный союзы, а также подчинительный союз и союзное слово: Денис помер. И когда я уезжал, старуха его вынесла мне гуся... (Пришв.); И прости, и уже навсегда, навеки... Потому что где же они теперь могут встретиться? (Бун.).*** [Справочник Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=380)

Получается, что запятая в данном примере не нужна.Но вот вам ещё одна цитата из справочника  ***Розенталя***, которая допускает постановку запятой:

Запятая обычно не ставится между присоединительным союзом (после точки) и союзом подчинительным, например: И кто вы такой, я знаю; А зачем это говорится, мне непонятно. ***Возможность постановки запятой после других присоединительных союзов связана с интонационно-смысловым выделением придаточного предложения, например:

**Однако, если вы так настаиваете на своём предложении, я готов его принять.*****

Comment: Мне ближе с запятой...

Comment: А я бы не поставила, потому что ОДНАКО здесь больше относится к придаточному: нужно что-то делать именно затем,чтобы добиться своего:не хочешь добиваться-не делай, А(ОДНАКО,но)чтобы добиться- нужно делать.